# A characterization in odd graphs

Tags: graph-theory

An odd graph $G$ is one in which every vertex has odd degree. I have to proof that if $X$ is a subset of vertices of $G$, then $|\partial(X)|$ has the same parity as $|X|$. It's a necessary and sufficient condition, in fact!

I have been trying with contradiction but just can't get anything... It seems like is just counting but can't seem how, any helpp would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is $\partial X$ the number of edges between $X$ and its complement?

Comment: I am sorry, yes it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$\sum_{v \in X} d(v) = | \partial X| + 2 i(X),$$ where $i(x)$ is the number of edges both of whose ends lie in $X.$ Take both sides modulo $2.$

Of course, the converse follows by taking $X$ to be a single vertex.

Comment: Never mind all the comments I've been editing... I get it now, I was thinking about the good formula (the one you posted above) but I wasn't using that all the vertices had odd degree... thanks a lot!!!!